# Retrieving id value in php

Tags: php

I am learning php and was wondering if it is possible to get the id value of a row that I want to delete.

For example

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $username = $row['username'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$username</td>";
    echo "<td>$id</td>";
    echo "<td>$name</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' name='delete' value='Delete' id = $id ></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
 }
```

So, how can I get this id value in order for me to delete the row?

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    DeleteRow($id);
    echo "<span style='color:green'>Row deleted</span>";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a hidden input array to delete all posted ids:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="ids[]" value="'.$id.'">';
```

Also don't forget to use prepared statements in your delete query.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code try this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$id = $row['id'];
$username = $row['username'];
$name = $row['name'];
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>$username</td>";
echo "<td>$id</td>";
echo "<td>$name</td>";
echo "<td>
     <form action='' method='POST'>
      <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'/>
      <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' name='delete' value='Delete'/>
     </form>
    </td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

To delete a row do this:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
  DeleteRow($_POST['id']);
  echo "<span style='color:green'>Row deleted</span>";
}
```